# How to avoid sending HTTP response in chunked transfer-coding

Tags: http, go, go-gin

I'm writing a HTTP server which has an endpoint which simply read a file from the file system and reply in HTTP response.

```
r.GET("/fs/:id/:filename", func(c *gin.Context) {

        ...
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fpath)
        if err != nil {
            render.Render(w, r, routes.NewErrNotFound(err))
            return
        }

        c.Writer.Write(data)
}
```

It is currently responding using chunked transfer encoding. With chunked transfer, server do not `Content-Length`. The low-powered device which consumes this API cannot allocate buffer ahead of time. It doesn't handle well.

Is there another way to transfer file and how can I control that?

Comment: `c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(data)))`

Comment: If they device cannot cope with chunked transfer encoding then it should not claim to support HTTP/1.1 in the first place. Instead it should use HTTP/1.0 which has no chunked transfer encoding yet.